# The largest tile in the 2048, groups of 3 variant? [moved to SE.Math]

Tags: algorithm, math

Question moved to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391780/the-largest-tile-with-2048-with-groups-of-3

A sentence to use up characters.

Comment: Shouldn't this belong better to http://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a mathematical puzzle, not programming.

Comment: You might find a solution here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716469/maximum-board-position-in-2048-game (maybe by replacing 2 with 3 in the formula?)

Comment: I think it'll be more complicated than that גלעד ברקן, it's hard to know what can actually be constructed though play in this variant, certainly I think at least 243.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping 3 and 6 doesn't create the same type of game. It would need to be 3 and 9 (3*3). Or you end up with two completely separate sets to merge, one with base 3 the other with base 6 (2*3).

In case you drop 3 and 9 then any 3^(2^min_moves) would be an acceptable objective just like 2048 = 2^16 = 2^(2^4)

EDIT:
Looks like I missed the part about merging 3 elements. That may need to have 3 and 27 (3^3) drop in. Also the objective would end up being 3^(3^min_moves) as merging 3 tiles is a move

Comment: Sorry, that was one hell of a typo, fixed. The major difference is gameplay/feel/strategy is created by the combining/merging of 3 elements to one, on such a small (4x4) grid.